# Sending multiple emails at checked checkbox in gridview not working

Tags: c#, email, gridview, checkbox

I would like some help with the following problem. I'm trying to send emails to users who are checked in a gridview. I've searched around and found many topics that look alike but I couldn't find a working solution. Well I know i'm missing something, maybe in my select statement. But I can't figure it out.

My code shows a gridview with let's say 2 users, many items and the email addresses from the users. I have selected 1 item for each user so 2 emails should be send. 2 mails are sent, but only to 1 email address, the email address he meets first in the database. I tried searching on userID but couldn't make that work, i'm still in my first few months at developping in .net.

See here my code:

```
    public void Email()
    {
        string conn = "Data Source=pc-...";
        LabelSendGridAbove.Text = "<b>Title</b><br /><br /> Text... <br /><br /> ";

        LabelSendGridBetween.Text = "<br /><br /> More text. " +
             "<br /><br /><br /> Regards, <br /><br /> " ;

        LabelSendGridUnder.Text = "<br /><br />--------------------------------------";


        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conn);
        sqlConn.Open();
        SqlCommand sendGrid =
            new SqlCommand("SELECT statement for gridview which will be send in the email ", sqlConn);

        GridView grd = new GridView();

        // Css for the gridview which will be send in mail     
        grd.BorderStyle = System.Web.UI.WebControls.BorderStyle.None;
        grd.GridLines = GridLines.None;
        grd.RowStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        grd.Width = 600;

        foreach (DataControlField field in grd.Columns)
        {
            field.ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Percentage(100 / grd.Columns.Count);
        }

        if (sendGrid != null)
        {
            grd.DataSource = sendGrid.ExecuteReader();
            grd.DataBind();
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        grd.RenderControl(htw);

        sqlConn.Close();


        foreach (GridViewRow r in GridViewOrder.Rows)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)r.Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBoxGetProduct")).Checked == true )
            {
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConn3 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conn);
                sqlConn3.Open();

                    if (((Label)r.Cells[0].FindControl("LabelEmailUsr")) != null)
                    {
                        Label txtUser = (Label)GridViewOrder.FindControl("LabelEmailUsr");
                        if (txtUser != null)
                        {
                            LabelTestMail.Visible = true;
                            LabelTestMail.Text = txtUser.Text.ToString();
                        }

                        SqlCommand emailAdres = new SqlCommand("SELECT tblUsers.tUserEmail FROM tblUsers", sqlConn3);

                        GridViewOrder.DataBind();

                        string email = Convert.ToString(emailAdres.ExecuteScalar());
                        LabelTestMail.Text = email;

                        try
                        {
                            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                            mail.To.Add(email.ToString());
                            mail.Bcc.Add("SomeEmail");
                            mail.From = new MailAddress("FromWho");
                            mail.Subject = "SomeSubject";
                            string Body = LabelSendGridAbove.Text + sb.ToString() + LabelSendGridBetween.Text + "<br /><img alt=\"\" hspace=0 src=\"cid:imageId\" align=baseline border=0 >" + LabelSendGridUnder.Text + "<BR>";

                            AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(Body, null, "text/html");
                            LinkedResource imagelink = new LinkedResource(Server.MapPath(".") + @"\logo\Logo.jpg");
                            imagelink.ContentId = "imageId";
                            imagelink.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
                            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imagelink);
                            mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
                            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("relay.skynet.be");
                            smtp.Send(mail);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Response.Write(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
            }              
      }
  }
```

I hope there aren't too many mistakes in this code. But if anyone knows what I should add to the code to make it work so it will send the 2 emails to the 2 different email addresses that would be very nice.

Thank you.

Comment: I changed code so it might make more sense. Still same problem though.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, two mails are sent but only to one address...the first address from the DB...am I correct?

If so, then the problem line is

```
SqlCommand emailAdres = new SqlCommand("SELECT tblUsers.tUserEmail FROM tblUsers", sqlConn3);
```

Seems to me that you are calling the same email address on each iteration of the for...each loop. Try adding a where clause and a search parameter.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your respons. I tried adding a where clause but i find it hard to write the correct code. At the moment it looks like:

`Label lblUsrId = (Label)GridViewOrder.FindControl("LabelId");
                            SqlCommand emailAdres = new SqlCommand("SELECT tblGebruikers.tUsrId, tblUsers.tUsrEmail " +
   "FROM tblUsers WHERE tUsrId=@tUsrId", sqlConn3);                           emailAdres.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tUsrId", lblUsrId);
GridViewOrder.DataBind();
string email = Convert.ToString(emailAdres.ExecuteScalar());`
I get an error at last line.

Comment: Changed the where clause to: `Label lblUsrId = (Label)GridViewOrder.FindControl("LabelId");
    SqlCommand emailAdres = new SqlCommand("SELECT tblUsers.tUsrEmail FROM tblUsers WHERE tUsrId=@tUsrId", sqlConn3);                          emailAdres.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tUsrId", lblUsrId.Text);
    emailAdres.ExecuteScalar();` New error says: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I'm kind off stuck here.